# How do I generate a SEF URL in a custom module instead of the real URL?

Tags: php, module, sef, url

In my module, this code is being used to generate the URL of the page:

```
JURI::base() . ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute(  $article->id,  $article->catid )
```

This works exaclty as it should and produces a URL that looks like:

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=83&catid=26&Itemid=162
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to get the module to generate the SEF URL for the current page. Something like:

```
http://example.com/resources/blog/83-illustration
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use JRoute for this:

```
rtrim(JUri::base(), '/') . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute(  $article->id,  $article->catid ))
```

but you don't need JUri::base() if you don't want to link to a different domain.

Comment: This worked and I will make it as "answered" but I was wondering why the new, SEF URL has two slashes after the domain name   http://bite-sized-joomla.com//our-work/illustration-photography/83-illustration

Comment: the reason is because JUri::base() returns a full uri with "/" at the end. and JRoute returns a absolute uri with a "/" at the beginning. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I believe that should be `rtrim(JUri::base(), '/')...` instead lf `ltrim(JUri::base(), '/')...` as the extra slash is at the end of the JUri::base() output.

Comment: I think you are right I updated the answer, thx.

Answer (score 4):

There is a system plugin called System: SEF. When enabled, this plugin scans the final HTML output just before it is sent to the browser, and replaces any non-SEF links with their SEF counterparts by running it through `JRoute::_($url);`. This only works for internal links though beginning with `index.php`, so it won't work if the link starts with `http://`.

Try removing `JUri::base()` (and thus removing the http:// from the link) and it should work if the plugin is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way of getting the correct root URL of the site. This also takes care if your site is in subfolder

```
$rootURL = rtrim(JURI::base(),'/');
        $subpathURL = JURI::base(true);
        if(!empty($subpathURL) && ($subpathURL != '/')) {
            $rootURL = substr($rootURL, 0, -1 * strlen($subpathURL));
        }
```

Then you can do

```
$url = $rootURL.JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute(  $article->id,  $article->catid ));
```